# Integrate react-native (web) into Django. How to add a prefix to all urls?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, deep-linking

I'm using react-navigation and trying to figure out how to add a prefix to all endpoints. Follows my `LinkingConfiguration` which doesn't do what I want:

```js
// const prefixes = [Linking.makeUrl('/app')];
const prefixes = ['example://app/', 'https://example.com/app/'];

const RootLinkingConfiguration = {
  prefixes,
  config: {
    screens: {
      Root: {
        screens: {
          Activity: {
            screens: {
              TabOneScreen: 'activityone',
            },
          },
          NewNfe: {
            screens: {
              Camera: 'camera',
              PostURL: 'posturl',
            },
          },
          Report: {
            screens: {
              ReportScreen: 'report',
            },
          },
        },
      },
      NotFound: '*',
    },
  },
};
```

I would like all endpoints to be prefixed by `app`, i.e:

```
app/activityone
app/camera
app/posturl
app/report
```

But I wouldn't like having to change them individually. How can I do this?

On the backend side I am pointing all urls starting with `app/...` to my react app. But I can't navigate properly with deep-links because my `react-navigation` linking configuration does not contemplate the `app` prefix.