# How to specify base URL path for react navigation Web?

Tags: react-native, expo, react-navigation

I am building a react-native app that uses @react-navigation.

Currently the goal is to host it on the path from our website. Eg: `https://mywebsite/app`

However when I deploy my app, it goes to 404 page, using `<Link to/>` component I can go to home page from the 404, which brings me to the root url `https://mywebsite`

Here's my linking set up

```
const linking = {
  prefixes: ["http://localhost*", "https://mywebsite/app"],
  config: {
    screens: {
      HomeScreen: {...},
      NotFound: "*",
    },
  },
};
```

Any way to make it work from a bath rather than a root?

Comment: I have found a similar question with no activity: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66728161/integrate-react-native-web-into-django-how-to-add-a-prefix-to-all-urls

Answer (score 1):

Ok so i got it working using this:

```
const linking = {
  prefixes: ["http://localhost*", "https://mywebsite/app"],
  config: {
    screens: {
      HomeStack: {
        path: "/app",
        screens: {
           HomeScreen: {...},
        }
      },
      NotFound: "*",
    },
  },
};
```

Essentially make a top level navigation stack that houses all the screens, mount the stack to the desired path